# Javascript 2d array of img's error in an object

Tags: javascript

```
function c_map(map_id){


    this.n = 0;
    this.m = 0;
    this.pic = [128];

    for(i = 0; i < 128; i++){
        this.pic[i] = [128];
        for(j = 0; j < 128; j++){
            //this.pic[i][j] = new Image();
        }
    }




    this.load_map = function(fnc){

        var xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                var lines;
                lines = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n");
                fnc.n = parseInt(lines[0]);
                fnc.m = parseInt(lines[1]);

                var k = 2;
                var i;
                var j;
                for(j = 0; j < fnc.m; j++){
                    for(i = 0; i < fnc.n; i++){
                        fnc.pic[j][i] = new Image();
                        fnc.pic[j][i].src = ""+parseInt(lines[k])+".jpg";

                        k++;
                    }   
                }
                alert(i);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","maps/0.map",true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }

    this.load_map(this);

    this.drawout = function(id){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d");
        canvas.drawImage(this.pic[0][0],100, 600);
        canvas.font="16px Georgia";
        canvas.fillStyle = "#000000";
        canvas.fillText("done" ,300,150);

    }
}
```

I have a 2d array of pictures in my javascript object. If i create objects in my constructor with new Image() its works perfectly and i can draw out in my drawout() function. But if i make the Image() objects to my array in my load_map() function(which needed to pass this as an object because xmlhttp would lost this on it's inside created function whats whatching if my xmlhttp is done), then i got this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'drawout @ map.js:53drawout @ game.js:25mainloop @ (index):32init @ (index):27onload @ (index):40

In the constructor i run load_map(); once, and nothing call it again. drawout() is called frequently in an outside loop. And even if i make the image objects in the load_map() function, i still can write out my image's scr with an alert, what is really strange for me. The file i request is a map file, contains the map's weight and hight and the type of each square in linel like:
2
2
1
1
1
1

It's 64x64 in my case.

I hope my question is clear, the way i do it is wrong, but i want to understand this error before i rework the code to don't load this many images without any reason, because all of them are the same.

If you ask any of it i'll response instantly.

Comment: *"`this.pic[i] = [128];`"* Does not create an array with 128 places in it, it creates an array with one entry in it, the number 128. This isn't the problem, because you don't have to pre-allocate the length of JavaScript arrays anyway (because they're [not really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)), but I thought I should mention it.

Comment: Thank you. So this.pic[i] = []; is the correct one, even if its not solve the problem, right?